# Shader output doesnt match Shadertoy

Tags: rust, opengl, gpu, glsl

I've been trying to display graphics using Rust, SDL2 and OpenGL (GLSL). The geometry renders fine, but I'm having problems with color in the fragment shader. Im currently rendering two triangles that together form a square covering the entire screen.

The vertices being drawn:

```
let vertices: Vec<f32> = vec![
// positions      
 1.0, -1.0, 0.0,   // bottom right
-1.0, -1.0, 0.0,  // bottom left
-1.0,  1.0, 0.0,   // top

-1.0,  1.0, 0.0,   // top
 1.0,  1.0, 0.0, // top right
 1.0, -1.0, 0.0,   // bottom right
];
```

This is my vertex shader:

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 Position;
out vec2 fragCoord;

void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4(Position, 1.0);
    fragCoord = Position.xy;
}
```

And my fragment shader:

```
#version 330 core

uniform vec2 u_resolution;
in vec2 fragCoord;
out vec4 fragColor;


void main() {
    vec2 uv = fragCoord.xy/u_resolution.xy;
    vec3 col = vec3(uv,0.0);
    fragColor = vec4(col, 1.0);
}
```

`u_resolution` variable is just the dimension of the screen (800 by 600). The corresponding render is:

[image: my output]

I submitted the following shader to Shadertoy.com, which should be equivalent to mine:

```
void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord ) {
    vec2 uv = fragCoord/iResolution.xy;
    vec3 col = vec3(uv,0.0);
    fragColor = vec4(col,1.0);
}
```

And the output on the site is:

[image: site output]

I dont understand what is happening here, is the geometry on the site somehow different? The eventual purpose of my program is to run a ray-marcher algorithm on the GPU, but I'm unsure as to what geometry to render. My guess was just a rectangle that  covers the whole screen (and transforms in line with the camera), but do I need something different? I want to be able to control the color of each pixel individually and render geometry with ray marching, not the rasterizer. Is my approach completely off?

<sub>Note: The far left side in the pictures are the result of bad cropping on my part.</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `fragCoord` and Shadertoy's `fragCoord` are actually not the same.

- Your `fragCoord` is in the range of `vec2(-1.0)` to `vec2(1.0)`, i.e. normalized device coordinates (NDC)
- Shadertoy's `fragCoord` is in the range of `vec2(0.0)` to `iResolution`, i.e. window relative coordiantes (which is what you want)

Shadertoy's `fragCoord` is simply [`gl_FragCoord.xy`](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/gl_FragCoord.xhtml), which is the window relative coordinate of the current fragment.

---

Additionally, the reason you're seeing 4 colors like that, is suggesting that the value of `u_resolution` is actually `vec2(0.0)`.

Because again, your `fragCoord` is in NDCs. So when a `fragCoord` component is below `0.0` it would result in negative infinite. Then when a `fragCoord` component is above zero it would result in positive infinite.

These infinite values would then effectively be clamped and result in the color extremes you're seeing.

You can mirror this behavior on Shadertoy by converting `fragCoord` back into NDC, and then dividing by `vec2(0.0)`.

```c
void mainImage(out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord)
{
    vec2 ndc = (fragCoord / iResolution.xy) * 2.0 - 1.0;

    vec2 wrongResolution = vec2(0.0);
    vec2 uv = ndc / wrongResolution;

    fragColor = vec4(vec3(uv, 0.0), 1.0);
}
```

[image: sahdertoy]

Comment: I did try using `gl_FragCoord.xy` instead of `fragCoord` but it just made the whole screen yellow. It seems to me that mine and Shadertoy's `fragCoord` are indeed the same, but mine seems to settle at extremes (and using `gl_Fragcoord` settles at extremes aswell).

Comment: No, your `fragCoord` is very clearly different that Shadertoy's by reading your code. Try replacing your `u_resolution` with `vec2(800.0, 600.0)` directly (while also using `gl_FragCoord`). If your whole screen turned yellow, that's suggesting to me, that your `u_resolution` is actually `vec2(0.0)`. Since then dividing NDCs with `0.0` would result in negative and positive infinite values. So it sounds like you're not actually updating the value of `u_resolution` correctly. (I've updated the answer)

Comment: Doing both of those things matches Shadertoy's output. I rechecked the code for setting `u_resolution`, and it seems moving it into the main loop fixes it. Thank you for all the help.